# How to Convert List to Json array in scala

Tags: json, list, scala, arrays

This is my code and here the return type is list but the list convert to array and the return type change to string

```
    @RequestMapping(value =Array( "/StandardChange.html"))
    @ResponseBody
    def  findDivisionOfStandards(@RequestParam  divisionid:Long):List[Division] ={

     var division:List[Division]= null
     if (divisionid != null) {

        division  = divisionService.findDivisionByStandardId(divisionid)            
    }       
     division  
    }
```

I tried this but this is not working

the Return type change **List** to **String** and the value change to **List** to **Json Array**

```
  @RequestMapping(value =Array( "/StandardChange.html"))
  @ResponseBody
    def  findDivisionOfStandards(@RequestParam  divisionid:Long):String ={

      var division:List[Division]= null

      if (divisionid != null) {

           division  = divisionService.findDivisionByStandardId(divisionid)         

        }   
       var divisionjsonArray=  division.toArray     **json convert should be here**

      divisionjsonArray
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
compact(render(decompose(division)))
```